# Задать фокус на инпуте и отобразить в нем значение из лейбла

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такая верстка

```
<li>
    <div class="show-task">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label class="">Task 1</label>  <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="edit-task">
        <form>
            <input type="text" value="" class="form-field-2">
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

Блок `edit-task` изначально скрыт (`display: none;`), блок `show-task` отображается.
При клике на `label` в блоке `show-task` блок `show-task` нужно скрыть, и вместо него показать блок `edit-task`, и в инпут, что внутри него, поставить фокус, и отобразить значение, которое было в `label` в `show-task`.

Не получается задать фокус на инпуте и отобразить в нем значение из лейбла http://jsfiddle.net/FY8WW/6/, подскажите, как можно это сделать?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("a").attr("hideFocus", "true");
 
 $('.show-task input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
  $(this).parent('.show-task').find('label').toggleClass('marked-task');
 });
 
 $('.show-task').hover(function () {
  $(this).children('.delete-task').toggleClass('visible');
 });
 
 $('.show-task label').click(function () {
  var value = $(this).html();
  $(this).parent('.show-task').addClass('inactive');
  $(this).closest('li').find('.edit-task').addClass('active').find('form-field-2').focus().val(value);
 });
});
```

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.task-list {
    width: 300px;
}
.task-list li {
    padding: 25px 0 16px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.task-list li:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
}
.show-task {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.show-task {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.show-task.inactive {
    display: none;
}
.marked-task {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.delete-task {
    float: right;
    display: none;
    color: #0000ee;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.delete-task:active {
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.delete-task.visible {
    display: block !important;
}
.edit-task {
    display: none;
}
.edit-task.active {
    display: block;
}
.form-field-2 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 0.25em 0 0.25em 0;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #FFA500;
    color: #A9A9A9;
    width: 280px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="task-list">
    <li>
        <div class="show-task">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class="">Task 1</label> <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="edit-task">
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-field-2">
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="show-task">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class="">Task 2</label> <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="edit-task">
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-field-2">
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="show-task">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class="">Task 3</label> <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="edit-task">
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-field-2">
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так походу http://jsfiddle.net/FY8WW/10/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("a").attr("hideFocus", "true");
 
 $('.show-task input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
  $(this).parent('.show-task').find('label').toggleClass('marked-task');
 });
 
 $('.show-task').hover(function () {
  $(this).children('.delete-task').toggleClass('visible');
 });
 
 $('.show-task label').click(function () {
  var value = $(this).text();
        var li = $(this).parent().parent();
  $(this).parent('.show-task').addClass('inactive');
  li.find('.edit-task').addClass('active');
        li.find('.form-field-2').focus().val(value);
 });
});
```

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.task-list {
    width: 300px;
}
.task-list li {
    padding: 25px 0 16px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.task-list li:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
}
.show-task {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.show-task {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.show-task.inactive {
    display: none;
}
.marked-task {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.delete-task {
    float: right;
    display: none;
    color: #0000ee;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.delete-task:active {
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.delete-task.visible {
    display: block !important;
}
.edit-task {
    display: none;
}
.edit-task.active {
    display: block;
}
.form-field-2 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 0.25em 0 0.25em 0;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #FFA500;
    color: #A9A9A9;
    width: 280px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="task-list">
    <li>
        <div class="show-task">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <label class="">Task 1</label> <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="edit-task">
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-field-2" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="show-task">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class="">Task 2</label> <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="edit-task">
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-field-2">
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="show-task">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class="">Task 3</label> <a href="#" class="delete-task">X</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="edit-task">
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-field-2">
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: уже понял. сейчас смотрю что не так

Comment: @Heidel, обновил ответ

Comment: лол, на самом деле, мой первоначальный код тоже рабочий, только я точку у класса в `find('.form-field-2')` забыла, чертова невнимательность.

Comment: я думал ты парень о_О

Comment: @mountpoint неa)